# Better way of getting array data from input in Laravel

Tags: html, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have a HTML code as below. Every time plus button click will create another row, of class="repeat" inclusive of all its inner elements. So basically each row will have input a,b,c,d,e and f.

```
<div class="row no-gutters mb-3 repeat">
    <div class="col-md-11">
         <input name="a[]" placeholder="a" class="mr-1" type="text">
         <input name="b[]" placeholder="b" class="mr-1" type="text">
         <input name="c[]" placeholder="c" class="mr-1" type="text">
         <input name="d[]" placeholder="d" class="mr-1" type="text">
         <input name="e[]" placeholder="e" class="mr-1" type="text">
         <input name="f[]" placeholder="f" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">    
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm add-more" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>    
    </div>
</div>
```

My code in PHP looks like this (Using Laravel framework):

```
foreach($request->a as $a){
    foreach($request->b as $b){    
        foreach($request->c as $c){        
            foreach($request->d as $d){            
                foreach($request->e as $e){                
                    foreach($request->f as $f){                    
                        $data = [                        
                            'a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c, 'd' => $d, 'e' => $e, 'f' => $f                        
                        ];
                        Abc::create([$data]);                   
                    }                
                }            
            }        
        }    
    }
}
```

All I need is a suggestion to improve the above PHP code. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try using a json data type in laravel

Answer (score 1):

Actually the foreach approach was wrong. We can add one more input element as hidden element as below to use as reference:

```
<input name="id[]" type="hidden">
```

Than in PHP we can do like this:

```
for($s = 0; $s < count($request->id); $s++){
    Abc::create([
        'a' => $request->a[$s],
        'b' => $request->b[$s],
        'c' => $request->c[$s],
        'd' => $request->d[$s],
        'e' => $request->e[$s],
        'f' => $request->f[$s]
    ]);
}
```